# Nested (?) SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having this table GROUPS:

```
COD | DESCR  
----+------  
001 | GRUP1  
002 | GRUP2  
003 | GRUP3
```

How can I achieve this result?

```
MONTH|GROUP  
-----+-----  
1    |GRUP1  
1    |GRUP2  
1    |GRUP3  
2    |GRUP1  
2    |GRUP2  
2    |GRUP3  

...  

12   |GRUP1  
12   |GRUP2  
12   |GRUP3
```

I need to list the months from 1 to 12 and inside each month the Groups.

To list months usually I do like this:

```
SELECT mes FROM ( VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12) ) [1 to 12](mes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `cross join`:

```
SELECT m.mes, g.group
FROM ( VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
     ) m(mes) CROSS JOIN
     groups g
ORDER BY m.mes, g.group;
```

Comment: Thank you.

I just added "Order By mes" tho achieve the result i want